# Python Pandas: Move nan and blank values to bottom

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample Pandas dataframe. In the last column, Warranty Start Date, I would like to push empty values to the bottom, and have NaN values on top of empty cells. The cells with actual data should be on the top. How would I do this?

The sort_values() method I have tried:

`production_df.sort_values(['Warranty Start Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)`

AFAIK it only does half the job. It pushes NaN values to the bottom, but blanks are ignored rather than placed at the end of the column. Here is an example of what I want:

[image: Sample Desired Result]

Comment: `production_df.replace('',np.nan).sort_values(['Warranty Start Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)` ?

Comment: @JuanC how would you do it without numpy?

Comment: Is there any reason you're avoiding numpy? Anyways `production_df.replace('',None).sort_values(['Warranty Start Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)` should work, but it usually isn't recommended to use it because `None` is more inconsistent than `np.nan`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you want to avoid NumPy?

Comment: Thanks @Juan C ! I originally thought it would be better to not have another unnecessary import/dependency but it looks like the non-numpy route is not recommended. As for why I wanted this, it’s so we can prioritize the rows with non-empty cells.